# SVN Restoring folders where user has no rights

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

We have have come across the following problem quite a few times.

The scenario is as follows:

A user has rights to Folder A with Subfolder 1, 2 and 3. The folders have all been checked out on his PC using Tortoise SVN.

After the project is completed, the user no longer needs access to Subfolder 3, and I remove the user from Subfolder 3 using the VisualSVN administrator on the server side, and the user deletes the folder in Windows from his PC. I can confirm the user is removed from the rights as he can no longer access the folders using a web browser or the Tortoise repo browser.

Yet when the now user does an update on the checked out folders, Subfolder 3 is 'Restored' on his PC each time.

Why is Subfolder 3 coming back even after I have removed him from the rights to that folder  on the SVN server, and how do we prevent that from happening?

We use Server 2008, and a mix of Windows Xp, 7, and 8 PC's. The folders are quite large, a few GB each (Engineering Projects with CAD drawings, photos etc), so doing a complete checkout is not possible every time I wish to correct this problem.

Answer (score 0):

An update restores deleted files from the hidden .svn folder where all the BASE versions are stored.
If you want to delete the folder, you also have to delete the hidden .svn folder of the working copy.

Comment: I only see one .svn folder on the top most folder, and it contains a folder called pristine and tmp. In pristine is a lot of subfolders named 00, 0a, 0b, 0c etc. I don't see any resemblance to the existing folders. Am I missing something with regards to your answer?

Comment: Probably you just need to get the user to check out a new working copy.

Comment: Checking out a new working copy is exactly what I am trying to avoid, as these projects can be 2 - 5 GB per project, and some users have 10 - 15 projects.